# Using coroutines and texture array for talking animation?

Tags: unity, c#, scripting

I was thinking of having random textures from a texture array being chosen every 0.5 seconds through a coroutine to imitate talking if something like talking=true. Not sure how I could set this up and such so I appreciate any help!

Comment: Your plan sounds sensible. How have you tried putting it into practice so far? Where specifically did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the community!

Not sure about texture changing, but if you would like to do that with sprites, here's an example.

```
public sealed class TalkingAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer _renderer;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite[] _sprites;
    [SerializeField] private float _spriteChangeInterval;

    public void StartTalking()
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(TalkingRoutine());
    }

    public void StopTalking()
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }


    private IEnumerator TalkingRoutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_spriteChangeInterval);
            _renderer.sprite = _sprites[Random.Range(0, _sprites.Length)];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work, but I would really recommend to do something like this through the [animation system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationOverview.html) instead. It's not just for 3d models. You can also use it for animating 2d objects by switching out their sprites. OP did specifically ask for a solution using an array and coroutines, but I think it should be mentioned nevertheless.